# how to check for any unsaved changes on client side onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to check of some temporary data which is unsaved by user? so that i can popup and ask user for unsaved changes?
or is there any other way to figure it out?

i am thinking of using some flag way to check if the user edit's something then i will change the flag and from this way i will be able to figure this out but this is not cheapest way as i have so many controls on the web page and so many jquery functions and don't want to update all jquery functions so they can change the flag.

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework, change tracking is enabled by default. You can also disable change tracking by setting the AutoDetectChangesEnabled property of DbContext to false. If this property is set to true then the Entity Framework maintains the state of entities.
You can do a foreach to get all entries with their statuses.

Comment: the data flows only on client side in memory cache, so need something in jquery etc

Comment: why don't you use cookies ?